# How to mock private static inner class using Powermock

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I am new to mockito+powermock. I am trying to mock a class which have private static inner class. I am facing ExceptionInInitializerError. Could someone please help me with properly initializing the class.

Error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ....................
    ....................
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.retail.xpd.pos.messaging.topics.TopicComponentHelper.<init>(TopicComponentHelper.java:10)
    at com.ibm.retail.xpd.pos.messaging.topics.NodePath.<init>(NodePath.java:11)
    at com.ibm.retail.xpd.pos.messaging.service.RetailPlatformService.<init>(RetailPlatformService.java:69)
    at com.tgcs.scrt.gui.components.PageManager$PageControlService.<init>(PageManager.java:216)
    at com.tgcs.scrt.gui.components.PageManager.<clinit>(PageManager.java:242)
    ... 69 more
```

Class looks like:

```
public class PageManager{
    .........
    .........
    private static class PageControlService extends PlateFormService{
    .........
    }
}
```

Mocking class in test case:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic( PageManager.class );
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're missing:

Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.

from:

https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

@Marcin - what a terrible, condescending answer. You often need to mock static classes. For example, in basho's riak client, the response class is a static inner class (which, from their POV, makes sense - only the client should be constructing responses). So if you want to mock what the client returns, you have to mock a static inner class.

Getting really tired of all the people responding to unit test questions with "don't mock X", or "that code you're testing is wrong", just because they don't know the answer.

Comment: +1 for 'Getting really tired of...'. Most of us here know how real companies deal with unit testing, and how we have to create unit tests with code that cannot be refactored, so seeing all these 'This is a horrible idea', 'You do not get the essence of Unit Tests' answers are totally awful and boring.

Comment: I completely disagree with you. You can wrap your call to a mocked static method in a class that you control and then you can mock that class. You shouldn't mock the types you don't own in general. I'm removing my answer cause that should actually be a comment. But I do think that someone is trying to solve an issue of wrong architecture with a wrong tool